# How do I trigger or call a function on INSERT to one table based on result of another table?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, insert

I know how to do this using SQL Server or Sybase, but can't seem to get it right using Postgres 9.4. I have a FUNCTION that is working as intended:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."welcome"(u_id INT DEFAULT 1234) 
  RETURNS "void" 
  AS $$
  INSERT INTO my_table_1 (title,body,category,user_id,created_at)
  VALUES ('Welcome!', '<some text>','general',u_id,now())
  $$ LANGUAGE sql
```

This FUNCTION works as expected when called as `SELECT welcome(1234);`

However, what I'm trying to do is call or trigger this FUNCTION based on the condition `AFTER` a new user gets inserted into another table and that user is the first and only user:

```
INSERT INTO my_table_2 (user_id,name,...) VALUES (5678,'John Doe',...);
```

and the following condition is met:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from my_table_2 WHERE <my conditions are met>;
```

returns exactly and only `1`

So, symantically, I'm trying to accomplish:

`call TRIGGER welcome(1234) AFTER INSERT into my_table_2 where my conditions are met`

I've seen some examples, and don't quite understand the `CREATE FUNCTION x() AS TRIGGER` syntax, and it seems that Postgres is steering me in this direction, but examples are lacking in my case.  Help! (and thanks in advance!)

Comment: @mark_s thank you for the pointer to Jon Skeet's [recommendations](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) for SO guidelines.  Most informative and useful!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the SQL standard, you define a `trigger` that fires a `trigger function` when a certain action is taking place. In your case you want to create an `AFTER INSERT` trigger whose trigger function calls your "welcome" function.

First the trigger function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION call_welcome() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  cnt integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO cnt FROM my_table_2 WHERE ...;
  IF cnt = 1 THEN
    PERFORM welcome(NEW.user_id);
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_call_welcome
AFTER INSERT ON my_table_2
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE call_welcome();
```

Comment: Patrick, not only is this an **EXACT** description of my goal, it is also the clearest Postgres example that I have come across.  Just modified and tested it - works **PERFECTLY**.  Very grateful - well done and thank you, sir!

Comment: Welcome for your high praise. Welcome also to PostgreSQL and on Stack Overflow!

Comment: just a quick note on my changes - aside from customizing my `WHERE` clause to meet my objectives, the `TRIGGER FUNCTION` also required a change from `RETURN` to `RETURN NEW` (I have updated your example for the edification of others who may benefit from your solution - again, many thanks!)

Comment: Well spotted on the `RETURN NEW`. The second bit about `</code></pre>` was not necessary; there are two ways of defining a code block: one with html tags, the other by indenting with 4 spaces, as in my answer.

Comment: @Jasper33: there are several examples in the Postgres manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: @patrick - thanks - on my first edit attempt, SO would not allow me to update my edits, perhaps because the first code block used `<pre><code></code></pre>` and the second block did not? So just shortcutting around SO's restriction.